# Run shell scripts in order

Tags: shell

I have 3 commands that I am trying to run when the system start as a cronjob.

```
# Sleep at startup
sleep 2m
#command num 1:
./trace.out
sleep 5

#Command num 2:
java -jar file.jar
sleep 5

#Command num 3:

sh ./script.sh
```

is there any way to make this script more efficient using a loop, some way to make sure every script is running before executing the next one.

Comment: as part of your development, you have to test your code enough to be sure you're calling the right program, and that is running correctly. What you have written should do exactly what you specify "make sure every script is running before executing the next one". Do you have a reason to believe one or all of the sub-programs aren't working? If so comment out the other parts of the script and just get one program to work, then uncomment the next and get it to work. Usually PATH problems. Change plan java to `/path/to/myInstallOf/java` (for example). AND use shell trace/debug feature, `set -vx`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am just worried if one script fail and I want to make sure the other scripts will not run until the precedent one is running, if not, the script will try again until the command executed and the program is starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use && between each command as it executes each command, only if the previous one succeeded! For example:

```
# Sleep at startup
sleep 2m
./trace.out && java -jar file.jar && sh ./script.sh
```

Comment: can i develop this solution to have a conditional if any of commands fails to write a message to a log file?

Comment: Not that I am aware of sorry. but you could determine if the command was successful as example: ./trace.out && echo "Success" && java -jar file.jar && sh ./script.sh Logical this would tell you wish command failed. However, maybe you could use something from this site to determine the exit code of a command: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-how-to-determine-the-exit-status-of-linux-and-unix-command/